# Cannot read property 'heading' of null

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, model-view-controller, ejs

My problem is I got an unexpected error at the browser end that says  **Cannot read property 'heading' of null**

also marks this error at the client page file like about.ejs and showing; in the snap attached

[image]

I have provided all the required codes related to this. I reviewed multiple times to find for what or to where the actual errror originated but did not able to fix it.

codes of  about.ejs

```
<%-include('./partials/header')%>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <h1>About Section</h1>
    <div class="card shadow mb-4">
        <div class="card-header">
            <form action="/admin/portfolio/create" method="post">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Edit About Page</button>
                </form>
        </div>
        <div class="card-header py-3">
            <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">About Area</h6>
           
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <form  action="/admin/about" method="post" >
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Headings:</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="heading" id="exampleFormControlInput1" value="<%=about.heading%>" >
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleFormControlInput2">Sub-Headings:</label>
                  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="subheading" id="exampleFormControlInput2" value="<%=about.subheading%>" >
                </div>


                  <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea id="editor1" name="content" rows="10" cols="80"><%=about.content%></textarea>
                  </div>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save & Update</button>
                
                </form>
               
                    </div>
                    </div>

</div>

<%-include('./partials/footer')%>
```

here is my router.js file

```
router.get('/admin/about',serverController.isAuthenticated,serverController.about)
router.post('/admin/about',serverController.isAuthenticated,serverController.about_post)
```

This is also my controller file

```
exports.about = async function(req,res){

    res.render('server/about', {
        about : await aboutCollection.findOne()
    })
}

exports.about_post = function(req,res){

    let about = new About(req.body)
    about.create().then(async()=>{
        res.redirect('/admin/about')
    }).catch(()=>{
        res.send('404')
    })
}
```

and finally this all about my model of about page

```
const aboutCollection = require('../db').db().collection('about')
const objectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID



const About  = function(about){
    this.about = about
}

About.prototype.create = function(){
    return new Promise(async(resolve,reject)=>{
        await aboutCollection.updateOne({}, {$set : 
            {
            heading : this.about.heading,
            subheading : this.about.subheading,
            content : this.about.content
        }
    })
        resolve()


    })
}

module.exports = About
```

Answer (score 0):

it's because about sent value of none at the `ejs tag` i mean

```
<%= about.heading%>
```

Do,

```
exports.about = async function(req,res){

    res.render('server/about', {
        about : await aboutCollection.find().toArray()
    })
}
```

Instead of,

```
exports.about = async function(req,res){

    res.render('server/about', {
        about : await aboutCollection.findOne()
    })
}
```

In my case, I did this; after trying then see error has gone.